# Paypal Internal Server Error Rest approval Payment

Tags: api, rest, paypal, payment

I have a problem when creating an approval Payment using REST API.
     i'm creating a payment with pyment_method = 'paypal'

```
 while i'm sending to paypal server my json file as 

"{"transactions":[
{"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":"12","details":{}},
"description":"This is the payment transaction description."}
]
,"links":[],
"intent":"sale","payer":{
"funding_instruments":[],"payment_method":"paypal"}
}"

this is 
result: Object
debug_id: "086b180fbe2f1"
information_link: "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR"
message: "An internal service error has occurred"
name: "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including elements you shouldn't be, and missing important ones. If you are setting up a PayPal payment you need to have cancel and return urls:

```
{
    "redirect_urls":{
        "return_url":"http://<return URL here>",
        "cancel_url":"http://<cancel URL here>"
    },
    "transactions":[
        {
            "amount":{
                "currency":"USD",
                "total":"12.00"
            },
            "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
        }
    ],
    "intent":"sale",
    "payer":{
        "payment_method":"paypal"
    }
}
```

See [Accepting a PayPal Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) for a guide

Answer (score 1):

Paypal frequently returns internal server error. This is common in sandbox mode.
The most common is to try again and get execute.

Try:
https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

In my case I set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and get meaningful response:

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"688b8ab4b2895"}
```

Instead of:

```
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"><ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.lang.NullPointerException</ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>
```